# My game does not autosave?

Tags: far-cry-3

I have played it almost 15 times, have completed upto third checkpoint all the times, but then when I quit and load the chapter, it starts from the scratch. Because of this I cannot progress any more in game as all that will be lost too if I quit. Here is a picture when I go back and reload:

[image]

You see chapter 1/0:00. It starts from the very beginning, "where is that mf" and all that BS.

Edit: P.S.- As the game said in beginning, pulsating gun animation never appears on checkpoints.

Comment: Two things. 1. Check to make sure your autosave is enabled.  2. You should upload your image instead of posting a link to it.

Comment: how do i check that autosave is enabled?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth it'll be somewhere in the games options